# Spotify apps-tutorial not working. Missing Dependencies: Framework compatible with api (version 0.2.3) does not exist

Tags: spotify

I just started the Spotify apps tutorial (for developing Spotify apps, obviously), but unfortunately can't get it working.  For reference, here are the steps I followed (from https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial)

1. Sign up for a developer account on Spotify
2. Open Terminal, `mkdir ~/Spotify`
3. `cd ~/Spotify`
4. `git clone git@github.com:spotify/apps-tutorial.git`
5. Download the latest version of Spotify
6. Open Spotify and type `spotify:app:tutorial` in the search bar

I've done all of these steps, except when I search for `spotify:app:tutorial:`, I get the following message:

```
Missing Dependencies
Framework compatible with api (version 0.2.3) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

A change was done last Friday which accidentally broke the API. It's fixed now and is working properly.